What is the meaning of this given verse?
What is the meaning of this given verse?
षड्जे षाड्जीममुद्भूतं श्रीरागं स्वल्पपञ्चमम् । सन्यामांशग्रहं मन्द्रगान्धारं तारमध्यमम् ॥१५९॥ समशेषस्वरं वीरे शास्ति श्रीकरणाग्रणीः ।

This verse belong to "Bhatkhande, Sangeeta Sastra Vol.3". Please refer link which takes you to page: 53, and you will see the verse on the page:
https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.326020/page/n68/mode/1up?view=theater
